# Change line spacing for normal text, but not in tabular or verse

Tags: environments, paragraphs, line-spacing, setspace, patching

```
\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing
```

I used above two lines to change the spacing in my document. This changes the spacing of the entire document.

My requirement is to change the line spacing in paragraphs only. I want to leave the `verse` and `table` environments as they are. I just want to change the paragraphs. 
I did not put paragraphs in any environment. Do I need to do that as well?

Comment: Are you actually referring to the `table` environment (a float environment) or do you mean `tabular` (producing the actual table)? If the latter is the case, please edit your question accordingly. You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit. And perhaps you could change the title to something more specific, e.g. "Change line spacing for normal text, but not in tabular/table or verse".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\AtBeginEnvironment{verse}{\singlespacing}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\singlespacing}

\usepackage{lipsum}% just for blindtext

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{verse}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{verse}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{tabular}{p{10cm}}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This patches the `verse` and `tabular` environment to use a `\singlespacing` at their beginning. The `table` environment isn't affected by `[doublespacing]` and thus doesn't need any patching, but you probably want to use `tabular`.

[image: screenshot of the output]

Comment: If the `tabular` isn't wrapped in the `table` environment (which it probably isn't for Aku's document) this won't work, and you'll have to patch the `tabular` environment in the same way you did the `verse` environment.

Comment: @Alan: Ah, thanks, that answer the question I just asked on your answer `:)`. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I am very new to TeX, this is the error I am getting ! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \AtBeginEnvironment
                       {verse}{\singlespacing}

Comment: @Aku: Did you put `\usepackage{etoolbox}` in your preamble? `etoolbox` is the package that provides the environment-patching command.

Comment: @Aku: Actually, if you used exactly what you wrote in your comment here, then there's an unnecessary space in between `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `{verse}{\singlespacing}` that might cause the error. Remove this space and try again.

Comment: I copied the code from here and ran it, did not modify anything and I am getting the above mentioned error. There is not space between     \AtBegin Environment and {verse}{\singlespacing}.  the spacing appeared in my comment was accidental.

Comment: @Aku: Is `etoolbox` installed on your system? What LaTeX distribution are you using? It didn't work when you just copied my entire example and compiled it? (btw: you can (and should) use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) in comments as well.)

Comment: I am using texlive-2011, I don't know how to check if certain package is installed or not.

Comment: @Aku: Try to compile `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{etoolbox}\begin{document}Foo\end{document}`. Any error messages?

Comment: @Aku let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1132/discussion-between-doncherry-and-aku)

Answer (score 5):

To locally change the line spacing in your document, use the environments `singlespace,` `onehalfspace` and `doublespace` provided by the `setspace` package. So, for instance:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{setspace}
\doublespacing

...

\begin{document}

...

\begin{singlespace}
  ...
\end{singlespace}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a book more than 1000 pages long. Paragraphs comes alternatively after a verse and table. Paragraphs is essentially explanation of verse. Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: Using the `\preto` or `\appto` macro provided by the `etoolbox` package, you can easily redefine `\verse` and `\endverse` to include `\singlespace` and `\endsinglespace,` respectively. Of course, you can also do this for other environments that shouldn't be typeset with `\doublespacing.`

Comment: Or even better (as suggested in the answer of @doncherry): Use the `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro of the `etoolbox` package.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine the `verse` and `tabular` environments to make them single spaced:

```
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\let\endoldtabular\endtabular
\renewenvironment{tabular}
   {\bgroup\singlespacing\oldtabular}%
   {\endoldtabular\egroup}
\let\oldverse\verse
\let\endoldverse\endverse
\renewenvironment{verse}
   {\bgroup\singlespacing\oldverse}%
   {\endoldverse\egroup}
```

Comment: Does `tabular` actually need redefinition? In my quick test it wasn't affected by the changed line spacing.

Comment: Yes. The double spacing option of `setspace` makes `table` single spaced, but not `tabular` itself.