# Reduce line spacing in minitoc package

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, minitoc

I am using the `minitoc` package to add chapter TOC's in a thesis. The entire document (including the main table of contents) is doublespaced, but I want the chapter toc's to be single spaced. I specify the `minitoc` options in the document preamble as:

```
\usepackage[tight,k-tight]{minitoc}
```

The resulting chapter toc's are still double-spaced, though.

How does one override the properties of the main table of contents to produce a single-spaced minitoc?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you're using the `setspace` package and its command `\doublespacing` to switch to, well, double-spacing, you can always enclose some part that needs to be singlespaced in a `singlespace` environment. Alternatively, you could issue the command `\singlespacing` before the start of the minitoc and then issue a `\doublespacing` command when it's done, as in

```
...
\singlespacing
\dominitoc
\doublespacing % or \onehalfspacing, or whatever
...
```

Comment: OK, that is the same solution as the one in the link given in my answer, but you were faster.

Comment: @Stephen: Manipulating `\baselinestretch` is fraught with occasional pitfalls. It's much safer in general to use the `setspace` package and then `\singlespacing` or, equivalently, `\setstretch{1.0}`. (The latter command may look more numerically precise and hence more scientific than the former...

Comment: For some reason this doesn't change the minitoc to singlespace in my file. There are two solutions that brought it down to 1.5 spacing, neither of which make any sense. These include:

`\begin{spacing}{0.0}`
`\minitoc`
`\end{spacing}`

and

`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.0}`
`\minitoc`
`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}`

Perhaps there is something in my thesis style that is overwriting the local line spacing changes?

Comment: Hi. If you've loaded the `setspace` package, you should be using the commands `\begin{singlespacing}` `\minitoc` `\end{singlespacing}` to start and end the single-spaced portions -- note the *single* part in the environment name. I'm afraid I'm unfamiliar with the `spacing` environment, so I can't help you there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, btw. According to [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_LaTeX), `\begin{spacing}{1.0}` `\minitoc` `\end{spacing}` is equivalent to `\setstretch{1.0}` (both belong to the `setspace` package. In my case, if I issue even `\setstretch{0.0}`, the `minitoc` spacing only reduces to oneandhalf spacing.

Comment: Maybe you should add a list of all packages you load in an addendum to your original question. Some other package must be setting some of TeX's "deep" variables related to line spacing; only if you list all packages do we have a chance to find out which one (or ones) are involved in this.

Comment: Wow, I've been using the `setspace` package for years and I didn't even know it provides the environment `spacing`... Incidentally, there are a couple of mistakes in one of my earlier comments: the single-spaced environment is called `singlespace`, not `singlespacing`. :-(

Answer (score 2):

for chapter tocs use

```
\begingroup
\parskip=1pt
\chapter{...}
\minitoc
\endgroup
```

You can also give package `chaptertoc` a try, it is easier to use, from my point of view

Comment: I've never heard about this `chaptertoc` package and sounds interesting (`minitoc` is powerful but an alternative could be useful); however, I haven't been able to locate it in CTAN. Where can I find the package?

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/change-line-spacing-for-normal-text-but-not-in-tabular-or-verse/26168#26168) might be a solution here, too. Otherwise

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
% The Minitoc here
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
```

might help.